# Why initializing an object of a value whose type there's a defined ctor doesn't invoke the copy constructor?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, copy-initialization

Hello I have a simple question: If I have a class that has a constructor that takes an integer for example then if I copy-initialize an object of that class then is copy-constructor or constructor is called:

```
class M 
{
    public:
        M(int) { cout << "M(int)\n"; }
        M(const M&) = delete;
        M(const M&&) = delete;
};


int main()
{

    M m = 9; // why M(int) is called but not a copy-ctor or move-ctor?
}
```

- AS you can see I have an ambiguity here: `M m = 9;` I think it is a form of `Copy-initialization` so normally I think the copy-ctor or move-ctor should be called. I've declared theme deleted to get an compile-time error but it works?

Comment: `M m = 9;` is just a different syntax for `M m{9};` (or any of the other 9001 initialization syntaxes in C++). Try `M n {1}; M m = n;`. This will invoke the copy-constructor.

Comment: If you want to avoid such implicit conversion, mark your constructor as `explicit`

Comment: Rules where adjusted at some points by the standard committee. Not sure about the reason. Before that, compiler were allowed to optimize away the constructor if the code would have compile.

Comment: @n314159: But why this code works on C++20 but not on C++14 and C++11?

Comment: @Maestro All code I posted should work from C++11 onward. If you have a problem you should be more specific.